# Why object spread throw error in latest Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, ecmascript-6

Please see this minimum spread code snippet

```js
{...(false && {hello: 'world'})}
```

[image]

Firefox version is 67.0.4（64 bit）

Comment: because `{` denotes a scope block here, and `...` is not allowed to be there. If you did `const o = {...(false && {hello: 'world'})}` that would have worked.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this should have been the case in all versions of FF that support spread operation. Before that you'd have still gotten an error but maybe worded differently. When has this worked?

Comment: wow, it actually worked!